En android al pulsar sobre el botón este cambia a otro, por que no sale los colores de la imagen?
Tengo este código puesto y funciona, pero los iconos me salen en gris y no como es la imagen realmente.
btn_recorder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rec_rojo);

Estoy trabajando con android studio API VanillaIceCream
Gracias por la ayuda.

Cómo es el botón? Puedes incluir alguna captura y el código XML y de la actividad?

Si la imagen "rec_rojo" que cargas para el botón en realidad tiene color rojo y se muestra en color gris, lo mas probable es que tienes otro recurso en color gris en alguno de los demás directorios /drawable, revisa todos y asegura que no tienes esa imagen en color gris.

